# Visual Studio does not remember publish credentials (password)

Tags: visual-studio, azure-web-app-service, publish

I switched to a new pc, and now whenever I want to publish my application to azure, I need to fill in the credentials. It remembers the username, but not the password.
This was not the case on my previous pc, where it remembered both.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- download the publishing profile on the azure portal for your web app. In it are the credentials you should use.
- right click on the project - click 'Publish'
- on the top, select the publish configuration that you want to edit (with the dropbox that is barely visible)
- click on the combobox 'more actions' and choose 'edit'
- click on the 'connection' tab to enter the password, and save

Comment: This also works for Web Deploy to any IIS server.